# Index Match + multiple criteria + return list/range

Tags: arrays, indexing, excel-formula, match

I am trying to look things up in a table and return them with a formula, with the following requirements:

1. There are two criteria (columns) to include in the look-up
2. Need to return the list of all matches rather than a single item

I have found ways of doing these things on their own (using more complex Index Match for #1 and using the “:” operator for #2 to specify a range and return a list in the form of an array), but whenever I try to combine them it doesn’t work.

I have shared an example below, where ‘Table 1’ is the source data and ‘Our selections’ are the references for looking up. Can someone please let me know a formula that can go in the mentioned cell that will return the green ‘Returned list’ of associated entries from the ‘Interaction’ column (of Table 1)?

I am running a Mac with Excel version 16.46
Thanks in advance!

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJWgL.png)

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTh7v.png

Answer (score 0):

The following page explains a similar case, only it's not returning an array. It works with the index. So you would have to put the formula in enough rows to show all matches:
https://www.xelplus.com/return-multiple-match-values-in-excel/

In your case the formula would be something like this:

```
=IF(ROWS($A$2:A2)<=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$18,$G$2,$B$2:$B$18,$G$3),INDEX($C$2:$C$18;AGGREGATE(15,3,(($A$2:$A$18&$B$2:$B$18=$G$2&$G$3)/($A$2:$A$18&$B$2:$B$18=$G$2&$G$3)*ROW($A$2:$A$18))-ROW($A$1),ROWS($E$2:E2))),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what column/row your data starts/ends, but I assumed your table starts at `A2`, you project selection is in `E2` and your filter starts at `E6`

In that case use the following array formula in `E6` and drag down:
`=IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,MATCH(1,(A:A=E$2)*(B:B=E$3)*(COUNTIF(E$5:E5,C:C)=0),0)),"")`
Array formulas are to be entered with `ctrl+shift+enter`

If you where to have office 365 this formula would do the trick:
`=FILTER(C:C,(A:A=E$2)*(B:B=E$3)*(C:C<>""))`
this will adjust to the number of occurrences automatically.